# Что значит, что в компьютере операция сложения не аддитивна?

Tags: информатика

Что значит, что в компьютере операция сложения не аддитивна?

Comment: а откуда такое предположение?

Comment: Ну, при работе с плавающей арифметикой это действительно так. Сумма двух чисел может быть не равна их сумме :)

Comment: А что означает слово «аддитивный» в вашем случае? Я знаю только свойства коммутативности, ассоциативности, наличия нейтрального и обратного элемента.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я подозреваю, что подобная формулировка не совсем корректна, потому что не ясно, что значит "в компьютере" и что значит "операция сложения". Но отвечу, как понял.

Каким бы ни был компьютер, его память ограничена. Если речь идёт о числах в регистрах процессора, то всегда существует максимальное число, а если прибавить к нему единицу, мы получим минимальное число, а вовсе не то, что ожидали. Скажем, у нас есть 8 бит со знаком. Максимальное число будет `0x7F = 127`, прибавим единицу, получим `0x7F+1 = 0x80 = -128`. Нарушено свойство аддитивности.

Далее, в плавающей арифметике ещё хуже. Самый простой пример: сложив большое и маленькое числа вместе, получим не их сумму, а снова получим большое число. Скажем, `1e30+1e-30=1e30`.

То же можно сказать о длинной арифметике. Рано или поздно память кончится - и попытка сложить два числа завершится неудачей... однако тут уже вопрос философский, считать эту неудачу нарушением аддитивности или нет.

Comment: Какое отношение эти рассуждения имеют к аддитивности? Вы рассмотрели строго обратный процесс.